# Flickr Authorisation with oAuth using Swift

Tags: swift, oauth, flickr

I wanted to get Flickr authorisation with oAuth, but I got empty response. Here is how I did.

1. Created base string like this (XXX..XX is oauth_consumer_key):

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D91133798%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1427542658

2. Genarate signature with HMAC-SHA1:

> 128974f0e49251f6bd705f7bf9dadbd3dafe90a4

3. Created request string with base string and signature like this:

> https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_nonce=61061285&oauth_signature=128974f0e49251f6bd705f7bf9dadbd3dafe90a4&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1427542658

4. I called the request string "requestStringSignature"

   ```
   var url = NSURL(string: requestStringSignature)
   var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) 
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
       request,
       queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
       completionHandler: {
           (response, data, error) -> Void in
           println(response)
       }
   )
   ```

   Response was nil.

Please help.